# Want to find the largest number among three number using copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

IN this program I want to take three inputs from the user and find the largest number among those. I also have to use the copy constructor. But I don't know how to do this.

I wanted to do a program using copy constructor which will take 3 inputs from the user and show the largest number.

```
class Largenum {
    public:
        int a, b, c;
    Largenum(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a > b && a > c)
            cout << "Largest number is: " << a;
        else if (b > c)
            cout << "Largest number is: " << b;
        else
            cout << "Largest number is: " << c;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    cout << "Enter three numbers:";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Largenum l(a, b, c);

    Largenum l2 = l;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good constructor should only *initialize* the object, not perform input, output or do the actual work. Your constructor doesn't do any initialization, but does perform the work of the object together with its output.

Comment: As for a copy-constructor, it will generally be created by the compiler. And for your case the compiler-generated copy-constructor will do the right thing (copy the (uninitialized) member variables values).

Comment: Your question sounds like: "I want to slice bread with a razor" - yest it is possible, but ... .

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you please elaborate on WHY do you want use the copy constructor for this purpose? Also, do you know what a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor should do what its name suggest, nothing more nothing less.
I'll suggest you the following:

```
class Largenum {
    Largenum() {}
public:
    static getLargeNum(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a > b && a > c)
            return a;
        else if (b > c)
            return b;
        else
            return c;
   }
};

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    cout << "Enter three numbers:";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    cout << "Largest number is: " << Largenum::getLargeNum(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```